# Matching item in list with item in column containing list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data feed where one column contains lists. I also have a list of values I want to detect. I want to create a new column that has 1 when one or more of the column values is in the list of values, and 0 when none of the items in the column list are in the detection list.

```
# df with list
       job               type
0        a              [300]
1        b         [234, 177]
2        c               [-1]

# Detection List
impacted = pd.Series([174, 175, 176, 177])

# Desired df
       job               type     risky
0        a              [300].        0
1        b         [234, 177].        1
2        c               [-1].        0
```

I've tried numerous techniques, but can't find the correct pattern to compare the column list to the detection list:

```
df.loc[df['type'].map(set).isin(impacted.str).any(1), 'risky'] = 1

df.loc[df['type'].isin(impacted), 'risky'] = 1

if set(impacted).intersection(df['type']):
    df.risky = 1
```

These all fail for various reasons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have your match list in a Series, you can make use of the `isin` and `sum` method:

```
df['risky'] = df['type'].apply(impacted.isin).sum(axis=1)
```

Which gives you:

```
  job        type  risky
0   a       [300]      0
1   b  [234, 177]      1
2   c        [-1]      0
```

The useful part of this is `sum` will also give you the number of matches, given:

```
  job             type
0   a            [300]
1   b       [234, 177]
2   c             [-1]
3   d  [174, 175, 176]
```

The result will be:

```
  job             type  risky
0   a            [300]      0
1   b       [234, 177]      1
2   c             [-1]      0
3   d  [174, 175, 176]      3
```

If all you care about is a `0` or `1` for True/False, use `any`:

```
df.assign(risky=df['type'].apply(impacted.isin).any(axis=1).astype(int))

  job             type  risky
0   a            [300]      0
1   b       [234, 177]      1
2   c             [-1]      0
3   d  [174, 175, 176]      1
```

Comment: Nice addition! Don't need it in this case, but I will certainly mark this for future use! ty

Answer (score 3):

If you work with pandas 0.25+ you can try `explode`:

```
df['risky'] = (df['type'].explode()
                  .isin(impacted).any(level=0)
                  .astype(int)
              )
```

Output:

```
  job        type  risky
0   a       [300]      0
1   b  [234, 177]      1
2   c        [-1]      0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Implemented this and get no errors, but 'risky' is all 0s :(

Comment: Maybe your lists are list of strings. If so, try `isin(impacted.astype(str))`. You should make sure that you have the same type in the list and in `impacted`.

Comment: Just saw that your comment is a cleaner implementation than where I landed.

Answer (score 0):

a straight-forward but rather slow (performance wise) way to do this would be to convert both the list & the series to set and check if the intersection is non-empty

```
df['risky'] = df.type.apply(lambda x: 1 if set(x).intersection(set(impacted)) else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

w00t! @QuangHoang led me in the right direction. Just needed to add this before the .explode line:

```
impacted = list(map(str, impacted))
```

The logic needed strings, not int. Now it works perfectly!